# Sound fading out

Tags: 20.04, sound

Whenever im watching youtube or just videos in general if the person in the video stops talking for even just a second the sound fades out and then just starts again a few seconds after the person has been talking. im on ubuntu 20.04 and im using razer nari wireless headset that uses a 2.5mhz dongle. Also i am on ferenOS that's based on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does the sound work with in-build speakers or a non-wireless headset?

Comment: ferenOS is NOT Ubuntu, and isn't supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @kanehekili its the same with other devices.

Comment: @waltinator sorry for the confusion. i figured it was since i use the ubuntu repo to install stuff. also because when i was looking up ubuntu based flavors ferenOS popped up when i was first doing research

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution was i had to set all other output devices to off. and if the output device happened to also be an input device (yeti microphones, razer headset) i had to set it to just be an input device or an output device and not both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).